# jQuery - How do I push a value into a global array in IE and Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, firefox

**Edit:** At least part of the problem was because `history` already exists (and I didn't know that). Thanks, everyone.

**Original:**

I have a function that pushes the value of an `<input>` into an initially empty global array named `history` then clears the input.

The code to push the value works fine in Chrome 21 and Opera 12, but not in IE9 and Firefox 15.

I've been researching this for a bit and found that if the array was local (created in pr() instead of $(document).ready as `var history = []`), it worked fine. I also tried declaring it outside of everything at the top of the file.

IE error: `SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'push'`

FF error: `TypeError: history.push is not a function`

How do I push a value to an empty global array in IE and Firefox?

Here's my code:

```
<input type="text" id="command" />
```

Then in my JS file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    history = []; // no var because that makes it global, right?
)};

$(document).keypress(function(e) {  
    if(e.which == 13) { // if enter     
        e.preventDefault();

        if($("#command").val() !== "") {
            pr();
        }
    }
});

function pr() {
    var text = $("#command").val();

    text = text.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, "");    // these two are supposed to
    text = text.replace(/[<>]/gi, "");            // sanitize the input

    history.push(text); // this where it gets hairy
    alert(history); // doesn't display anything in IE/FF because .push failed

    // do a bunch of other stuff that isn't relevant
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: call it something other than `history`.

Comment: Not sure if typo but $(document).ready(function() { isn't closed properly. Also, you can declare something as global easily from anywhere by going window.<variablename> = ...

Comment: Also history is a very bad name for it, as history is already an object, very likely to be the problem, rename it to something like scriptHistory

Comment: @jezternz Yeah, sorry, that's a typo. I see, I'll try something other than history. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare var outside of $(document).ready() and also please note that history is already a global variable in browsers.

```
// I changed the variable name. from history to historyVar
var historyVar = []; // this makes it global


$(document).ready(function() {
    // FIX: declaring it here will not make it global to your js.
    // history = []; // no var because that makes it global, right?
}); // **NOTE: was not properly closed, I added some ); to do the fix**

$(document).keypress(function(e) {  
    if(e.which == 13) { // if enter     
        e.preventDefault();

        if($("#command").val() !== "") {
            pr();
        }
    }
});

function pr() {
    var text = $("#command").val();

    text = text.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, "");    // these two are supposed to
    text = text.replace(/[<>]/gi, "");            // sanitize the input

    historyVar.push(text);

    // do a bunch of other stuff that isn't relevant
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Part of the problem was that "history" already exists as a built-in object.

Comment: Besides for not calling it history, which is the object for browser history, you could also use window.variableName to force it to the global scope.

Comment: D'OH! I totally forgot about that one. Yep history is an object in most browsers. I'll revise my answer.

Comment: nmenego: Thank you! And totally understandable, I didn't even know "history" existed.

@ReneGeuze Thanks for the tip!